# The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, duplicates, having-clause

This is unfinished database for selling train tickets.
[image]
I want to create primary key for RouteId in Route table, but i got an exception:

The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Route' and the index name 'PK_Route'. The duplicate key value is (1).

But there are no another key.

I think the problem may be that initially I had 2 tables Route and RouteStation, than I delete table Route and rename RouteStation to Route.

Another themes on this site does not help me.
I also tried to see key for this table, but output was empty:

```
SELECT Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = 'Route'
```

Comment: Does your table already contain data?

Comment: ........ @GMB yes

Comment: You cannot add a unique index on a column which does not contain duplicate values.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the content of the `route` table. The message tells you that you have duplicate values in columns that are referenced by constraint `PK_Route` - probably `RouteId`. You can exhibit them with:

```
select RouteId from Route group by RouteId having count(*) > 1
```